# Notifications from service

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

I'm trying to send notification with additional action. I'm registering it in service:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ACT_ACCEPT);
receiver = new notifReciever();
this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class notifReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BR_Action", intent.getAction());
    }
};
```

I'm sending it like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
PendingIntent contentIntentAccept = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    new Intent(this, AppService.class).setAction(ACT_ACCEPT), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

n = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentTitle("Test")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setVibrate(pattern)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_accept, "Accept", contentIntentAccept)
    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent).build();
```

But string with tag `"BR_Action"` isn't added to the Log.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue Alex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onReceive()` will only be called when you start the Intent and not just register it. Try using `startActivity(new Intent(ACT_ACCEPT));`